# Replacement of Windows Shell search of Outlook 2013

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-office-2013, windows-desktop-search

Unfortunately with Outlook 2013, it is no longer possible to search emails from Windows Shell ("Windows" key and type), which is incredibly frustrating as my emails are split over many psts and valuable knowledge is in specific emails somewhere there.

My question : is there a hack to re-enable or a 3d party app that achieves the same - unified file and email search?

Missing features: http://blogs.office.com/2012/12/19/outlook-2013-deprecated-features-and-components/

Comment: Good suggestion! Will give it a spin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copernic Desktop Search. It is a CPU and disk hog, but it does a good job of searching your Outlook e-mail. It also can be configured to include a search field in the Windows task bar.

Answer (score 0):

To save someone the trouble, I'm listing all software I found that achieves the function:

- [X1 Search](http://www.x1.com/products/x1_search/)
- [Copernic Desktop Search](http://www.copernic.com/en/products/desktop-search/). Copernic would not index e-mails, but rather attachements in e-mails which isn't an exact replacement of Windows Desktop Search

Comment: CDS will index e-mails. I am not sure why it only indexes attachments for you.